# Logical implication in an empty theory

Tags: logic

How does implication work if we have an empty theory?

For example, given an empty theory Γ = { } and two propositional atoms A and B, can we say that Γ⊨A→B? If no, which logical conclusions (involving A and B) can we get from Γ?

Comment: The theorems of an empty theory are the tautologies.

Comment: But no formula "p to q" can be taut if p and q are distinct atoms.

Comment: If the theory is empty what are "A", "B" and "→"? You need at least some language defined to write formulas and derivation rules and/or semantics to use connectives and ⊨.

Comment: A theory is usually closed under the logical consequence relation of a logic. So, as Mauro says, a theory with no axioms contains all and only the tautologies or logical truths of the logic.

Comment: @Conifold, A, B, and -> would be parts of the language. My reading of the question is that he is asking about a theory with no axioms, not a theory over an empty language.

Comment: @DavidGudeman An empty theory cannot depend on language. As soon as the theory is dependent on language, for example `A`, the theory is not empty: it holds the proposition `A`.

Comment: @RodolfoAP, if A is a proposition, then it is not a language. A language (in formal logic) is a set of symbols and a set of rules for forming those symbols into well-formed formulas or WFFs. A calculus is a language plus a set of rules of inference. Each rule maps a possibly empty set of WFFs to another WFF. A logic is a calculus plus a mapping of WFFs to some domain of interest. A theory is a set of WFFs in a logic closed under the rules of inference. If the logic has tautologies, there is no truly empty theory, but you could have no axioms so there would only be tautologies.

Comment: Sorry for late replying. My point was the following: if A is false in Γ, then A→B must be true in Γ. But, as you can see, I was wrongly assuming that if Γ={ } then Γ⊨¬A. This is false as long as we adopt the open-world assumption. Thank you all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In formal logic, a theory is a set of sentences. (*Sentence* here is a term of art meaning a well-formed formula with no free variables.) Usually a theory is closed under the relation of logical consequence of some underlying logic. So, if the theory is axiomatizable, the theory contains all the axioms together with all their logical consequences.

A theory can be 'empty' in the sense of having no axioms, but as soon as you close it under logical consequence, it contains all the sentences that are the tautologies or logical truths of the logic itself.

If Γ is a theory with no axioms, and A and B are specified to be distinct atomic sentences, then the sentence A → B is not a theorem of Γ, since it is not a tautology. This does not mean that A → B is false, it just means that it is independent of the theory. Its truth depends on the truth values of A and B, and the theory has nothing to say about those.

Sentences that are theorems include:

1. ¬(A ∧ B ∧ ¬A)
2. A ∨ B ∨ ¬A
3. (A → B) ∨ (B → A)

In other words, any tautology of the underlying logic is a theorem. I'm assuming here that we are using classical logic, and → is the material conditional.

Answer (score 0):

> How does implication work if we have an empty theory? For example, given an empty theory Γ = { } and two propositional atoms A and B, can we say that Γ⊨A→B? If no, which logical conclusions (involving A and B) can we get from Γ?

You cannot infer anything from nothing. No premise, no conclusion.

You have all the usual logical truths involving two propositions A and B, such as the Modus ponens (A → B) ∧ A ⊢ B etc., but if A and B are not assumed, then A → B and B → A are both false.

Comment: The OP says: "two atoms". Maybe this is relevant... You say "two propositions A and B [...] then A → B and B → A are both false." Except in case A and B are the same.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA "*Except in case A and B are the same*" If you assume that then this is one premise and then your Γ is not empty.